# Blender not displaying animated keys

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, keyframes, graph-editor

I am trying to animate a material, but the animated keys are not showing in the graph editor.

Can anyone give me a clue, please? Shall I activate any kind of addon, feature, etc? Or is it a bug on blender?

I am using blender version 2.91.0. Below a print from my situation. I also attached a MWE .blend file. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select both the object and the node with the animated property:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! That works! I would never imagine that I should select both... in six minute I will check this as answer. Thank you again!